# Apache logging: Are there any alternatives to piped logging that allow for automatic compression?

Tags: apache-2.2, logrotate, log-rotation

Are there any alternatives to Apache's rotatelog that will also compress logs? Logrotate is not an option due to requiring a restart. Ideally this would be a utility that can be used to pipe logs from apache to it, similar to how rotatelog operates. I am ware a script and crontab would do the job but I was hoping something nicer was already out there.

Thanks,

Comment: Doesn't logrotate have a "copytruncate" option, that should avoid the restart?

Comment: `logrotate` actually performs a `graceful` restart of the `httpd` process, not a restart.